# Force postgres to escape all values in response

Tags: postgresql, slick, slick-pg

Is there a way to make postgres escape all the values in the response to a query?

Especially for cases like `({xx(yy)zz})` (a text value in an array field of a composite type) which would escape as `({"xx(yy)zz"})` (or something like that).

Comment: Escape for what? What result would you expect for that text in an array in a composite type? What system is going to parse the output?

Comment: I'm trying to work around and/or fix a bug in slick-pg specifically.

Comment: As a workaround, just don't query composite types as a single result column. Query their individual fields instead.

Comment: querying the column with `to_json` is a better work around imo, since it retains the structure of the composite type. but really getting postgres to escape things would be best.

Comment: Can you show the code that is parsing the value? Fixing that would be best.

Comment: join the party https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/pull/511